# How to convert string to float

Tags: c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am converting color values to string using string.Format.

How to convert the same values to float. 
Here is the code I did.

```
public string RGBToU(Color col)
    {

        string temp = string.Format(" aRGB({0}, {1}, {2})", 
              col.R / 255.0 ,
              col.G / 255.0, 
              col.B / 255.0
        );
        return temp;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean convert to float? what is your required output?

Comment: I want the values col.R,col.G,col.B as a float , divided by 255

Comment: Where do you want them? what isn't working right now?

Comment: Function should return them.

Comment: Presently i am returning string but i want to return float.

Answer (score 1):

Use Float.valueOf(String) to convert